# Why does `Wall.render(context)` only work on its own?

Tags: javascript, foreach, html5-canvas

I am working on the beginnings of a platformer. I am attempting to render an array of walls to a canvas. If the `Wall` is represented directly by a variable, it renders. But, if it is inside an array, accessing it and then rendering it does not work.

```js
function Box(x, y, w, h) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.center = function () {
    return [x + w / 2, y + h / 2];
  }
}

function Wall(x, y, w, h) {
  Box.call(this, x, y, w, h);
  this.settings = {
    color: "#888",
    collides: true
  }
  this.render = function (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.settings.color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}


var walls = [new Wall(0, 350, 400, 400)];
const context = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"))[0].getContext("2d");

walls[0].render(context);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

It doesn't work if I use classes.

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Box {
  
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  center() {
    return new Point(x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
  }
}


class Wall extends Box {
  
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    super(x, y, w, h);
    
    this.settings = {
      color: "#888",
      collides: true
    }

  }
  
  render(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.settings.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

//GAME CODE

var walls = [new Wall(0, 350, 400, 400)];
const context = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"))[0].getContext("2d");

walls[0].render(context);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I expect to see the `Wall` rendered as a rectangle with the color `#888` in the position specified in the constructor, but I see nothing. In fact, I don't even see an error message. Why is it so?

Comment: So you are saying both cases don’t work?

Comment: @FelixKling yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your snippets are working, but the reason you are not seeing anything is because you haven't specified the size of your `<canvas>` element. So the coordinates you set in `[new Wall(0, 350, 400, 400)]` render the square out of the canvas bounds and thus makes it invisible.

Whenever I change the `x` and `y` value of the `Wall` constructor to `0`, the rectangle shows.

```js
function Box(x, y, w, h) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.center = function () {
    return [x + w / 2, y + h / 2];
  }
}

function Wall(x, y, w, h) {
  Box.call(this, x, y, w, h);
  this.settings = {
    color: "#888",
    collides: true
  }
  this.render = function (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.settings.color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}


var walls = [new Wall(0, 0, 400, 400)];
const context = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"))[0].getContext("2d");

walls[0].render(context);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Box {
  
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  center() {
    return new Point(x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
  }
}


class Wall extends Box {
  
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    super(x, y, w, h);
    
    this.settings = {
      color: "#888",
      collides: true
    }

  }
  
  render(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.settings.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

//GAME CODE

var walls = [new Wall(0, 0, 400, 400)];
const context = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"))[0].getContext("2d");

walls[0].render(context);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I later found that a canvas only renders things within its width and height. So the HTML changes to

```
<canvas width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

or whatever arbitrary width and height you want.